# Gitlab x jira integration: the issue doesn't transit between statuses

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration, transition

I have a gitlab repository and I've properly integrated with Jira. Every time I commit mentioning the Issue Id, I can see a comment inside the issue.

The problem occurs when I add the commands #done or #time in my smart commit. Both of them appear in the comment as a string and don't do anything (transition between statuses or log time).

This shows that the integration is correct but the commands are not. I included the transitions id inside the jira setup on gitlab and my user has admin permission. Also I'm using the same email both on gitlab and jira.

An example of commit message:

```
MCMAPP-1 #time 1w 2d 4h 30m #done #comment yessss
```

What I expect is that #time logs the work time inside the issue and #done sends the issue to the column 'Done'.

But what I got was the output as comment inside the jira issue:

> User
> 3 days ago
>
> User mentioned this issue in a commit of project/repository:
> 'MCMAPP-1 #time 1w 2d 4h 30m #done #comment yessss'

Comment: I have no experience with Jira, but for me it seems like Jira does not recognize the key words. Are they working you comment the issue? If yes does the user, which you set up during the integration, have the rights to perform the actions?

Comment: They are not working when I comment the issue and the user has the rights to do it